# Need to check answer-Factoring out from surds

Tags: real-analysis

If I am  to take out a factor of $n^{3/2}$ from the top and bottom of the expression:
$$\frac{\sqrt{3n^3+2n} +\sqrt[\large 3]{2n^2+3n}}{n\sqrt{2n}+n+\sqrt{2n}}$$

Can someone please give me the final answer, not the working out so that I can check. I have got an answer but it takes me too long to write it as I don't know how to use MathJax.

Comment: I think he meant $n^{3/2}$ not $n^3/2$

Comment: @amWhy Thanks. I won't do that from next time.

Comment: @gt6989b yes u r right

Comment: Please let me know if the denominator is correct: Is there a coefficient of $2$ in the first square root, and/or is the term $n$ supposed to be under the first square root?

Comment: @amWhy at the bottom the first term is supposed to be nsqrt(2n)and that is where you get 2n^3/2